# Understanding data validation

Tags: vb.net

I am working on an assignment for school where I have to validate a data entry. My first issue is that running the function does not produce an error message when I run the code and use any other letter as customer type.

My second issue is that the 40% discount for the Else clause that is commented out is applying even though it is commented out.

```
Private Sub GetDiscountPercent(customerType As String, subtotal As Decimal,
                               ByRef discountPercent As Decimal)
    If customerType = "R" Then
        If subtotal < 100 Then
            discountPercent = 0
        ElseIf subtotal >= 100 AndAlso subtotal < 250 Then
            discountPercent = 0.1D
        ElseIf subtotal >= 250 Then
            discountPercent = 0.25D
        End If
    ElseIf customerType = "C" Then
        If subtotal < 250 Then
            discountPercent = 0.2D
        Else
            discountPercent = 0.3D
        End If
        'Else
        'discountPercent = 0.4D
    End If
End Sub

Private Sub btnExit_Click(sender As Object,
        e As EventArgs) Handles btnExit.Click
    Me.Close()
End Sub

Private Sub ClearResultBoxes(sender As Object,
        e As EventArgs) _
        Handles txtCustomerType.TextChanged, txtSubtotal.TextChanged
    txtDiscountPercent.Text = ""
    txtDiscountAmount.Text = ""
    txtTotal.Text = ""
End Sub

Function IsValidCustomerType() _
As Boolean
    If IsValidCustomerType = "R" Then
        MessageBox.Show("Customer Type has to be R or C or T", "Entry Error")
        txtCustomerType.Select()
        Return False
    Else
        Return True
    End If
    If Not IsValidCustomerType = "C" Then
        MessageBox.Show("Customer Type has to be R or C or T", "Entry Error")
        txtCustomerType.Select()
        Return False
    Else
        Return True
    End If
End Function
End Class
```

Comment: The code you have written is VB .Net not VBA. VBA does not use "return", does not support "AndAlso" etc.  Please edit your tags to show the correct language your are using.  Your question is not explained well.  You should explain what the inputs are and what the expected outputs are.

Comment: Any part of the code that is commented out will not run. Period. Therefore, if you get a result that indicates that the code ran nevertheless you may safely assume that another procedure ran in place of the one you expected to run.

Comment: *"My first issue"*, *"My second issue"*. If you had taken the site tour when prompted then you would probably know that you MUST NOT ask multiple questions in a single post on SO. You MUST ask a question that can have a single, self-contained answer. You need to edit your post to address a single issue only. Provide ALL and ONLY information relevant to that issue. If you have another issue, post another question for that, containing ALL and ONLY the information relevant to that issue. You need to do your part to help us help you, which means learning how to use the site properly.

Comment: There is nothing in the code you've posted that calls the `sub`s that do the validation. You also have some obvious logic errors in the out of context code you've posted. In fact, the code as written here should not even compile, which means it can't run. Please post your actual code in the form of a [mre].

Comment: You need to debug your code. Set a breakpoint and step through the code line by line. That way, you can see EXACTLY where and how the behaviour differs from your expectations and what data is in use at the time. Even if you still can't fix the issue, you can provide us with ALL the relevant information.

Answer (score 0):

> I am working on an assignment for school where I have to validate a data entry. My first issue is that running the function does not produce an error message when I run the code and use any other letter as customer type.

Speculating that this is wrong:

```
Function IsValidCustomerType() _
As Boolean
    If IsValidCustomerType = "R" Then
       ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
        MessageBox.Show("Customer Type has to be R or C or T", "Entry Error")
        txtCustomerType.Select()
        Return False
    Else
        Return True
    End If
    If Not IsValidCustomerType = "C" Then
        MessageBox.Show("Customer Type has to be R or C or T", "Entry Error")
        txtCustomerType.Select()
        Return False
    Else
        Return True
    End If
End Function
End Class
```

You've declared that this function returns a boolean. You cannot compare this to a string in a meaningful way, and if option strict is on it won't even compile.

Even if you could compare a bool with a string the logic of this is wrong. If you managed to make Type = C, then the code will never reach that check because it either returns true or false (in this case false) because C is not R, so while C is valid, you'll never check for it being C, because the code will only ever consider if it's R or not

You need to stop coding and write out your algorithm using pen and paper

> My second issue is that the 40% discount for the Else clause that is commented out is applying even though it is commented out.

Gonna go out on a limb here and say that because this code is wrong, or because of some other compiler error elsewhere, you're seeing a dialog that says "There were build errors. Whould you like to run the last successful build?" and youre saying "Yes", and you're running a version of the app where that code isn't commented out..